# How to integrate microsoft claity analytics tool in flutter apps?

Tags: android, flutter, cross-platform, native, ms-clarity

I want to integrate Microsoft clarity with the Flutter application. There is no proper documentation/information available over the Internet. Microsoft says it can be integrated with native android, react native and ionic apps. How can we use android sdk and make platform calls from Flutter?

Comment: I guess it's not possible yet, someone would need to write a plugin/widget. I created the issue here, maybe we'll know more: https://github.com/microsoft/clarity/issues/393